# angular js: Embed the templates or call each when needed, which way is better?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I am building a one-page application with Angular JS (1). And I ended with 20 html templates for 20 views/routes.

Now, I am wondering if it's a good idea to simply include all of these templates in the the page directly (using the `<script type="text/ng-template" id=" ... .html">`), thus eliminating the need for Angular to go and fetch each template separately. Which will definitely better the application performance.

But this of course will be costly on the application loading time; I ended up with 1000+ lines file because of all of these templates being called in the same file.

What do you think is better choice here? I myself comfortable with including all the templates in the page, because this way moving among routes will be much faster.

PS: I know that Angular JS caches the view templates, which of course solves the problem in hand, but any changes I will make on these templates wont be reflected on the user's end, because of the cache! And that's why I think it's a good idea to include the templates in the page, because any changes I make will be surely reflected. What do you think ?

Comment: It looks like you already know all preconditions that are needed to answer this question, nothing can be added here besides the personal opinion (which is offtopic on SO). I guess you can do benchmarks and see which alternative gives better performance in your particular case, nobody else can decide this for you.

Comment: @estus Yes, I was aiming for votes on this matter. And yes probably benchmarks is the way to make a decision here. I just wanted to hear from  other how would they implement this, and if there was a better way.

Comment: This totally depends on the particular app and its trade-offs. The option you've forgotten is something like `html2js`, may be cleaner than `text/ng-template`. Templates can also be minified during build process, but it isn't a big deal if they are gzipped. I prefer synchronous `template` templates instead of `templateUrl`, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: I didn't know about html2js, It's actually a great option here. Thanks.